# How to extract images from video file?

Tags: ubuntu, video, images

I mean, how to generate images files from a video like screenshots.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/984850/linux-how-to-extract-frames-from-a-video-lossless | https://askubuntu.com/questions/587686/how-to-extract-images-from-a-video

Answer (score 46):

Try with `ffmpeg`

`ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi -r 1 -f image2 image-%3d.jpeg`

You can read the documentation [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html)

- `-i inputfile.avi` The video input file is inputfile.avi
- `-r 1` extract 1 image per second of video. Replace that number for the number of images you want to get per second.
- `-f image2` force image output format, you may probable be able to omit this since the program tries to choose the output images format from the file extension.
- `image-%3d.jpeg` name of the output images, the %3d indicates that the output generated images will have a sequence number there of 3 decimals, if you want the number padded with zeroes you just need to use %03d.

Comment: your link seems be broken

Comment: @Nolwennig. Fixed, not as specific as the previous one but at least is the official documentation and hardly to be broken.

Comment: `-r 1` is for the number of images per sec. So for 60ips, or 24, it's `-r 24`. 
And to limit the extract, it's `-ss [start] -t [duration]`.

Comment: Thanks, work fine on Xubuntu

Comment: it does not work : [swscaler @ 0x5560a2cf5500] [swscaler @ 0x5560a2d05300] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly

Answer (score 7):

I have just downloaded the latest version of VLC for Windows 32 - 2.1.2 Rincewind and it works fine to do this.

Steps:

1 - Click Tools > Preferences and click radio button All

2 - Scroll down and click the + sign next to Video to expand

3 - Scroll down and click on Scene Filter and fill in the info for Directory Path prefix (where you want to save frames). Don't click Save.

4 - Scroll up and click on the word Video under Filters

5 - Click the check box for Scene video filter and click Save.

6 - Open and run a video and it will save .png's

7 - To stop saving frames go back to step 5 and uncheck Scene video filter.
Easy really once you know where to find the settings.

Comment: I had to restart VLC to get changes to the Scene Filter preference to take effect. My platform is macOS; not sure if this applies to Unix/Linux/Win versions. VLC 3.0.11.1.

Answer (score 6):

In VLC you can right click, Video, Take Snapshot

Comment: This sounds a bit labour-intensive if one would need images for e.g. each frame in  scene.

Comment: Unfortunately on Linux VLC crashes. (I found postings dating back to 2015, so this is a really old problem)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
#!/bin/bash
source_dir="."
output_dir="."
input_file_types=(avi wmv flv mkv mpg mp4)
output_file_type="jpg"

convert() {
        echo "" | ffmpeg -ss $ss -y -i "$in_file" -an -f image2 -vframes 1 "$output_dir/$out_file"
}

for input_file_types in "${input_file_types[@]}"
do

        find "$source_dir" -name "*.$input_file_types" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' in_file
        do
                echo "Processing…"
                echo ">Input  "$in_file
                # Replace the file type
                out_file=$(echo $in_file|sed "s/\(.*\.\)$input_file_types/\1$output_file_type/g")
            echo ">Output "$out_file

# get video duration
#    fulltime=`ffmpeg -i "$in_file" 2>&1 | grep 'Duration' | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//`;
#    hour=`echo $fulltime | cut -d ':' -f 1`;
#    minute=`echo $fulltime | cut -d ':' -f 2`;
#    second=`echo $fulltime | cut -d ':' -f 3 | cut -d '.' -f 1`;

#    seconds=`expr 3600 \* $hour + 60 \* $minute + $second`;
#    ss=`expr $seconds / 2`; # from the middle of video



    ss=`expr 10`; # from the 10sec of video



    # Convert the file
                convert "$in_file" "$out_file"

                if [ $? != 0 ]
                then
                    echo "$in_file had problems" >> ffmpeg-errors.log
                fi

                echo ">Finished "$out_file "\n\n"
        done
done
```

Comment: Tom : your script does not work : [image2 @ 0x56081d0f9b00] The specified filename '././video-nano.jpg' does not contain an image sequence pattern or a pattern is invalid.
[image2 @ 0x56081d0f9b00] Use a pattern such as %03d for an image sequence or use the -update option (with -frames:v 1 if needed) to write a single image.

Comment: @Marietto That message is a warning, not an error — it doesn't stop ffmpeg writing the file anyway.