# How to extract every 10th frame from a video?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, conversion

I have a video and I want to extract every 10th frame as I am getting way too many images.

`ffmpeg -i out1.avi -r 1 -f image2 image-%3d.jpeg`

[How to extract images from video file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185877/how-to-extract-images-from-video-file)

Comment: usually video has at least 25 frames per seconds - so using `-r 1` you get image every `25th` frame. If you want to get every `10th` then you will have even more images.

Comment: No i should have less images because i am only getting 1/10 of the batch @furas

Comment: you means every 10th image from images generated by this code - not every 10th frame from video. Use  `-r 0.1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want 1/10 of what you have now (when you use `-r 1`) then use

```
 -r 0.1
```

It will get `1 frame every 10 seconds` instead of `1 frame every 1 second`.

```
 ffmpeg -i out1.avi -r 0.1 -f image2 image-%3d.jpeg
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you really what every 10th frame from video then you can use `select` with `modulo 10`

```
ffmpeg -i out1.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,10))" -vsync vfr image_%03d.jpg
```

but it may gives more images than before.

If video has `25fps` then `-r 1` gives image every 25th frame. And if video has `60fps` then gives image every 60th frame. So it gives less images then this code which get image every 10th frame.